# Will crypto currency mining hardware work fine for machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, hardware

I've found that because of recession in crypto mining business a lot of mining rigs are available on sale in pretty reasonable prices. For around $1000 we can buy used machine. Will rig like this work fine for machine learning:

```
6x NVIDIA GTX 1070 8GB
Intel Celeron G3900
120GB SSD
DDR4 8GB
Asus Z 170 Pro Gaming
```

We are a small development company and looking for good priced rig efficient enough to teach some models on it. Such hardware seems to have a lot of CUDA cores, but what might be a bottleneck?

Comment: You might want to add some details about the target kind of ML process and volume of data, otherwise I doubt anybody can answer.

Comment: @Erwan at start we are looking to run NVidia's superslomo with around 2-3 GBs of video samples